# Poisson distribution in two disconnected region

Tags: distributions, random-variable, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Suppose  $N$ is a RV such that$$N\sim Pois(\lambda)$$
and $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ are two Random Variable distributed in two disconnected region called $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ respectively and $N=N_{1}+N_{2}$

**Then is it true that**
$$N_{1}\sim Pois(\lambda \cdot \frac{|R_{1}|}{|R_{1}|+|R_{2}|})$$
$$N_{2}\sim Pois(\lambda \cdot \frac{|R_{2}|}{|R_{1}|+|R_{2}|})$$
where $|R_{1}|$= Area of the region $R_{1}$. If this is true, please give me a reference.

(I know this much which is that  if $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are independent RV that have Poisson Distribution with parameters $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$, then $X_{1}+X_{2}=Z\sim Pois(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2})$, in the above $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ do satisfy this property)

Comment: You might want to consider a Spatial Poisson Point Process. Let $R$ be the region of interest, then a homogeneous Poisson Process has the number of points appearing in $R$ as $N(R)\sim Pois(\lambda|R|)$ Consequently, for any set of disjoint regions which cover $R$, such as $R_1\cup R_2=R$, then the number of points falling within $R_1$ is also Poisson, where $N(R_1)=Pois(\lambda |R_1|)$. I think your error was that $|R|=|R_1|+|R_2|$ should have appeared in your distribution of $N$. Otherwise on the right track.

Comment: @user1848065 I think I know what you are saying. Is it still possible for you to give me a good reference so that I can read about it more.

Comment: Try these notes? For the basic properties, I like this: https://www.columbia.edu/~jwp2128/Teaching/APML_lecture_notes.pdf. For more details: https://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/8501/points.pdf

Comment: @user1848065 Thank you so much.